# login expires before timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code in my web config for login

```
<forms name="HonareZendegi" timeout="4300" defaultUrl="/admin/Default.aspx" loginUrl="/Login.aspx" />
```

and this one for clicking on login button:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtLoginName.Text, ckbremember.Checked);
```

but I have no idea why when I upload my project on my host my login keeps expiring after a short time...like 2 minutes or so...

how can I prevent this?

Comment: Are you using any load balancers?  Or are you in a web farm?  If so do all of your nodes have the same encryption key?

Comment: The server's application log should also show the reason why the authentication ticket may have been rejected

Comment: What is your sessionState configuration in web.config?

Comment: AgustinCoder:I don't get the first comment...and about the second one no it doesn't show anything

Comment: Win: I have no sessioState...

Comment: Are you deploying your application locally or to a shared hosting environment? Did my answer work or not for you ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the `sessionState` timeout in your `Web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="4300" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That's great. Please accept my answer to your question.